# How to create a chrome extension that redirects to a particular link automatically?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hi I want to create a chrome extension so that when the user is on the page example1.com he would automatically be redirected to example2.com even before the page loads. this should work whether or not the user types in the url or goes there through a link.

Please help me in this!

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In background page:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if(tab.url.indexOf("http://example1.com") == 0 && changeInfo.status == "loading") {
        chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {url: "http://example2.com"});
    }
});
```

Comment: wonder if there is an extension that does this already. I was also looking around for such a solution; quite similar to ( I think; not sure ) foxyproxy in firefox. It had a regex based rewrite configuration, which was dead handy!

Comment: @CodeMedic Try to ask it on superuser.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Chrome's webRequest API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) to redirect your request when it matches a particular Url. Here is a sample code:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  modifyUrl, { urls: ['http://example.com/'] }, ['blocking']
);

modifyUrl: function(details) {
  if (details.url === 'http://example.com/') {
    return { redirect: 'http://www.requestly.in/' }
  }
}
```

Here are some details about using onBeforeRequest method:

1. first arugument, is your callback handler which is invoked whenever a request is intercepted which matches your Url patterns provided as second argument
2. second argument, A set of Urls or url patterns or Regex which tells chrome to intercept those Urls
3. third argument, requestOptions which can be `blocking` or `requestBody`.

You can read about webRequest API [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest)

Just in case you are looking for an already-made solution that can do the trick for you, you can checkout [Requestly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa/) which does the same work for you. It even allows you to match your url with three operators

- Equals: Strict match
- Contains: Specify any string which comes in url
- Matches: A JS based regex which matches something in url

Have a look at this screenshot for better understanding.

[image]

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Downvote for MASSIVE INEFFICIENCY of using `<all_urls>` match pattern and then testing each and every URL requested with JS. Please fix this and I'd be happy to upvote as this is the correct approach in general.

Comment: @Xan Thanks man for identifying the SCOPE OF IMPROVEMENT in the answer. I have corrected it and also added some details about using `onBeforeRequest` method.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need an extension for this. Just redirect `example1.com` to the IP of `example2.com`, then create a virtualhost on example2's server wich will reverse proxy the requests to the live host.

Comment: There is clearly a use-case for @user764894 's question. What if you do not have control on the servers. You are just a user who access a server on a corporate network that resolves as something.com when inside the network and something.company.com when outside the network ( VPN ) ? It does need a client based solution; i.e browser extensions.